# How to monitor Jenkins using Datadog?

Tags: jenkins, datadog

The [datadog plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Datadog+Plugin) has been installed on Jenkins. Once installed the Datadog API key and hostname had to be entered in Jenkins. Both tests have been passed. However, when a new check has been added to Datadog querying for jenkins checks does not return any jenkins checks.

**Desired situation**

The aim is to monitor Jenkins builds using Datadog:

- When did a build start
- When did a build finish
- Duration of builds (jenkins.job.duration)
- Whether jobs have been completed (jenkins.job.completed)
- Status of a build (jenkins.job.status)

**Attempts**

- The datadog agent has been installed on Jenkins
- The jenkins host is recognized by datadog
- The datadog agent that resides on the jenkins is up according to datadog
- According [this documentation](http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/jenkins/) some files need to be added to datadog in order to enable jenkins monitoring in Datadog, but it is not possible to access the box as it is hosted by datadog itself.
- According the integrations tab of datadog UI the Jenkins plugin has been installed and configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag (jenkins.job.status) should be added to every build in Jenkins in order to find the tag in datadog.

[image]

Once the build has been finished, the tag is added to datadog.

Comment: Where are we supposed to find these options? I was not able to find and extra step to add to builds that contains DataDog in its name. Also, the general configuration options for DataDog do not have any tagging options. Yes, the plugin is configured and using the test button reports suceess.

Comment: @sorin Have you installed the [datadog plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Datadog+Plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

There are presently two methods of monitoring Jenkins with Datadog:

1. [Jenkins Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Datadog+Plugin)
2. Deprecated [Jenkins Agent Check](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/blob/master/checks.d/jenkins.py)

Configuring #1, the Jenkins Plugin, will provide what you need with all configuration being set in Jenkins proper.  We discourage using #2 at this point and plan to remove it in a future release of Datadog.

Comment: Jenkins agent check was actually removed https://github.com/DataDog/dd-agent/pull/2688

Comment: Correct, it was deprecated at the time of my post but has since been retired entirely.

Comment: You can update your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

[The official integration](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-jenkins-datadog/) looks like your best bet for this now.